# How to find the index at which the same dictionary key occurs more than one time in swift3?

Tags: arrays, swift3, xcode8, alamofire

I am using the Alamofire+Objectmapper for getting the response from JSON and I have got the following array response:

```
{
        "id": 6,
        "name": "XYZA",
        "address": "Ireland",
        "phoneNumber": "",
        "latitude": 30.678899,
        "longitude": 18.546789,
        "operatingDays": [
            {
                "days": [
                    "Sun",
                    "Mon",
                    "Tue",
                    "Wed",
                    "Thu"
                ],
                "times": [
                    "09:00-12:00",
                    "16:00-21:00"
                ]
            },
            {
                "days": [
                    "Fri"
                ],
                "times": [
                    "17:00-22:00"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "India",
        "address": "ABCDE",
        "phoneNumber": "",
        "latitude": 27.23333,
        "longitude": 57.8654,
        "operatingDays": [
            {
                "days": [
                    "Sun",
                    "Mon",
                    "Tue",
                    "Wed",
                    "Thu",
                    "Fri"
                ],
                "times": [
                    "08:00-12:00",
                    "17:00-21:00"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

For looping through this i am using the code:

```
if let threeDayForecast = response?.data {
          for forecast in threeDayForecast {
            print(forecast.name ?? "")
            print(forecast.longitude ?? "")
            print(forecast.latitude ?? "")
            print(forecast.operatingDays)
            self.shopLocation.add(forecast.name ?? "")
            self.shopAddress.add(forecast.shopaddress ?? "")
            for operatingDays in forecast.operatingDays! {
              print(operatingDays.days)
              print(operatingDays.times)
              self.operatingDays.add(operatingDays.days)
              self.operatingTime.add(operatingDays.times)
            }
          }
        }
```

So you can see that at id value 6 we have got multiple value same key date and times. So is it possible to know at what index this happens? I mean in this at index 0 this happens for key operatingDays.

So for getting this i coded the following:

```
 if (forecast.operatingDays!.count == 2)   {

                    print("The culprit: \(index)")
                  }
```

So i need to get the index of the array where it contains more than one dictionary. How is it possible?

Comment: For dictionary with `id : 6` the `operatingDays` key is an array of two dictionaries, each with `days` and `times` keys with array values. There are *no* day values repeated and no identical time ranges. So I think you need to explain "got multiple value same key date and times" better. What do you expect the resulting "index" you are looking for to be in this example? What approaches have you tried to compute it? Edit your question, do not add the extra details in comments. Once you've done this it will help people to help you, and someone probably will.

Comment: @CRD please see the edits

Comment: So you have an array of dictionaries, each dictionary has a key `operatingsDays` whose value is an array. And you want to find the index(es) in the outer array of the dictionaries where the key's array has more than one element? What have *you* tried? A loop, standard method, something else? Why did it not work?